No overload matches this call error while using useSWR with an array key or an object key
I am using Next.JS (v14.2.15) and useSWR (v2.2.5) to build a frontend solution. I don't use any server part and would like to deploy it as static pages.
I found that if I use an array or an object as a key of the useSWR(), there always an error.
Here is a minimal reproducing code for the array version. (If I replace the [ string, RequestInit ] by { url: string, init: RequestInit } and also change the first argument of useSWR() invocation, there would be the same error.) :
import useSWR from "swr"

export default function Page() {
  async function fetcher<T>([
    url, init
  ]: [
    string,
    RequestInit,
  ]): Promise<T> {
    const response = await fetch(url, init)
    const result = await response.json()
    return result
  }

  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR<{message: string}, Error>([
    '/api/test',
    {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'tester',
      }),
    }
  ] as [string, RequestInit], fetcher)

}

And the error message is
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type '<T>([url, init]: [string, RequestInit]) => Promise<T>' has no properties in common with type 'SWRConfiguration<{ message: string; }, Error, BareFetcher<{ message: string; }>>'.

The error is because typescript cannot find a useSWR() overload to match current invocation, but actually, I think it should match this overload:
    <Data = any, Error = any, SWRKey extends Key = StrictKey>(key: SWRKey, fetcher: Fetcher<Data, SWRKey> | null): SWRResponse<Data, Error>;

And I also found that if I change the fetcher signature to
  async function fetcher<T>([
    url, init
  ]: any): Promise<T>

the error would disappear. But in that way, I will lose the strong typing in the fetcher function.
Here is the sandbox of this code: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/xhpjl2
My question is why this happens and how I can fix this with keeping strong typing.
